# reading a date with sscanf

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I've got to read a date format (dd-mm-yyyy;) from a char* string using sscanf with this line of code:

```
sscanf(string, "%[^-]-%[^-]-%[^;];", day, month, year)
```

where day/month/year are char* string of 3/3/5 elemets each.

In this way it works but when i try to use day/moth/year as `integer` variables (with same `sscanf`), I got a `0 0 0` value when i use `printf` on them. If i change `sscanf` to

```
sscanf(string, "%d-%d-%d;", day, month, year)
```

I got `segmentation fault`.

Anyone can help me? Using K&R book, I didn't find a solution.

Comment: How are `day`, `month` and `year` declared ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the `int` variables:

```
int day, month, year;
sscanf(string, "%d-%d-%d;", &day, &month, &year);
```

`sscanf()` returns the number of assignments made, recommend checking the return value before using `day`, `month` and `year`:

```
if (3 == sscanf(string, "%d-%d-%d;", &day, &month, &year))
{
}
```

Comment: it's correct but I swear I tried with &day... before but didn't work .-.

Comment: @ArrigoPierotti, did you change the type of `day` from `char[3]` to `int`?

Comment: day/month/year changed into int but didn't worked. Now it works, dunno xD