# How do I separate integers from a string and manipulate them in C?

Tags: c, string, integer

I am scanning for a date in the format mm-dd-yyyy and I need to take out three ints and use them for multiple things. How can I create three integers with mm dd and yyyy? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading a date with sscanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071342/reading-a-date-with-sscanf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to use fgets for all input.
The do/while loops will continue until valid input is taken.
This only validates the month. Something should be added to verify day and year.
Check the return of sscanf to make sure the needed items have been successfully scanned.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char line[100] = "";
    int scanned = 0;
    int valid = 0;
    int mm = 0;
    int dd = 0;
    int yyyy = 0;

    int x;

    do {
        printf("\n\t\t\t1) Input date (mm/dd/yyyy) to find days passed");
        printf("\n\t\t\t2) Input passed days to find date in the year");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\tYour choice (1/2): ");
        if ( !( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input found EOF\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ( ( scanned = sscanf(line, "%d", &x)) != 1) {
            valid = 0;
        }
        else {
            if ( x == 1 || x == 2) {
                valid = 1;
            }
            else {
                valid = 0;
            }
        }
    } while ( !valid);

    if(x == 1) {
        do {
            printf ( "enter date mm-dd-yyyy\n");
            if ( !( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin))) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input found EOF\n");
                return 1;
            }
            if ( ( scanned = sscanf ( line, "%d-%d-%d", &mm, &dd, &yyyy)) != 3) {
                valid = 0;
            }
            else {
                valid = 1;
                //validate the values for mm dd and yyyy
                if ( mm < 1 || mm > 12) {
                    printf ( "invalid month try again\n");
                    valid = 0;
                }
            }
        } while ( !valid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`sscanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) call from `<stdio.h>`.

```
char line[80];
int m, d, y;

fgets(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

sscanf(line, "%d-%d-%d", &m, &d, &y);
```

It is better to use fgets+sscanf instead of scanf directly, because scanf has the notorious `\n` issue and does not check buffer lengths.

Comment: And do not ignore the return value of `sscanf()`

Comment: its returning numbers much larger than it should, and not allowing me to input... it's returning m = 3952640 d = 0 y = 4200896 (This is before it is even allowing me to enter a date. Nothing changes when I input a date)

Comment: @xing this is my code 
int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("\n\t\t\t1) Input date (mm/dd/yyyy) to find days passed");
    printf("\n\t\t\t2) Input passed days to find date in the year");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tYour choice (1/2): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if(x == 1)
    {
        char line[80];
        int m, d, y;
        printf("Please input date (mm-dd-yyyy): ");
        fgets(stdin, sizeof line, line);
        sscanf(line, "%d-%d-%d", &m, &d, &y);
        printf("\nMonth: %d\nDay: %d\nYear: %d", m, d, y);